# Algebraic vector bundles on affine punctured plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I wonder if it is true that all vector bundles on the punctured affine plane are trivial, and I would like to have a reference in that case.

Comment: Yes, use the Corollary after Theorem 4.1 in Horrocks' paper "Vector bundle on punctured..." plus the fact that any vector bundle on the whole affine plane is trivial. 

Comment: Or, one can quote algebraic Hartog's Lemma plus the fact mentioned above.

Comment: Using Cech cohomology, the claim is equivalent to $\mathrm{GL}_n(k[X,Y]_{X \cdot Y}) = \mathrm{GL}_n(k[X,Y]_X) \cdot \mathrm{GL}_n(k[X,Y]_Y)$. I wonder, is there a purely algebraic proof (similar to Hazewinkels *Short and elementary proof of Grothendieck's Theorem on algebraic vector bundles over the projective line*)?

Comment: The topological statement is that $\pi_3(BU(n)) = 1$. It seems interesting to note that $\pi_3(BO(n)) = Z_2$ for $n$ large enough. Is there some algebraic avatar of this nontrivial class, maybe a vector bundle with nondegenerate symmetric form?

Comment: The conjecture of Serre: Is every algebraic vector bundle $E_{alg} \to\mathbb C^n$algebraically trivial , When $E $ is stabilized; see Bass, H.: Algebraic K-Theory. New York: W.A.Benjamin Inc. 1968. Now my conjecture is that serre conjecture holds on special affine variety in thesense of Griffiths see page 82 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389905

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Hailong Dao, for the answer! Algebraic Harthog's lemma says that if $A$ is a noetherian normal domain, then $A$ is the intersection of all localizations of $A$ at prime ideals of codimension 1. What should $A$ be in my situation?

For $n=1$, $H^1(X,GL(n,\mathcal O))$ classifies the vector bundles of rank $n$ on $X$-- is this true also for $n>1$? Should I use $A=\{1-$cocycles with values in $GL(n,\mathcal O)\}$, with respect to the covering by the open affines $D(x)$ and $D(y)\subset\mathbb A^2$? I suppose that all vector bundles over the affine pricipal open subsets $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ are trivial. Then a non-trivial vector bundle on $\mathbb A^2_*$ would give a nontrivial bundle also on $\mathbb A^2$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Martin! All I need is to understand the result, but of course it would be a very nice bonus if it could be understood by means of a short and elementary algebraic proof!

Comment: Yes this was my idea (except that I don't want to extend the vector bundle to $\mathbb{A}^2$ as in Hailong's comment (which is an answer)). For every $n$ there is a bijection between the set of isomorphism classes of rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$ and the Cech cohomology *set* $\check{H}^1(X,\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal{O}_X))$, even for an arbitrary ringed space $X$ (so this is just a fancy way of stating that vector bundles can be equivalently described by transition functions).

Comment: PS: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/faq, your "answer" should have been a comment.

Comment: Thanks Martin - the reason I posted it as an answer was that I couldn't post comments after I had left the page and come back again without creating a user account. I think the cookies disappeared somehow. I'm sorry for that. Is it correct that the actual way of extending the vector bundle to $\mathbb A^2$ would be to use algebraic Harthog's lemma on 1-cocycles with values in $GL_n(\mathcal O_X)$? I.e. ''extend the transition funtions to the origin''

Comment: I would very much appreciate some help in reading Horrocks' article: plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-14/4/689.full.pdf.

First of all I wonder if $\mathcal O_X$ -- ''the sheaf of local rings'' -- is just the sheaf of regular functions on $X$? I can't think of a sheaf for which $\mathcal O_X(U)$ is a local ring for every open $U$.

My main question is whether Corollary 4.1.1 really can be used to conclude that every vector bundle on $\mathbb A^2_*$ is trivial? It seems that there's a condition on $A$, from the very first page, that $A$ be local. But $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is not local. 

Comment: Dear Anonymous: I don't have Horrock's paper in front of me right now, but I would guess Corollary 4.1.1 states that a vector bundle on the punctured affine plane can be extended to a vector bundle on the affine plane. The triviality of a vector bundle on the affine space is called Serre's Problem, which was solved independently by Quillen and Suslin (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen–Suslin_theorem).

Comment: Dear Mahdi Majidi-Zolbanin, Corollary 4.1.1 states that ''If $A$ is 2-dimensional and regular then every bundle on $Y$ is free.'' Here, as far as I understand, $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, $X=Spec(A)$ and $Y$ is the punctured spectrum $X\setminus\mathfrak m$. A bundle is a locally free coherent sheaf. 

Comment: Another approach would perhaps be to ''projectivize the base'' somehow, and use the fact that vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1$ decomposes into line bundles. Line bundles on $\mathbb A^2_*$ are trivial. Can this be used to see that there is only the trivial vector bundle on $\mathbb A^2_*$?

Comment: Even better! Suppose $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ is a vector bundle on the punctured affine plane. Then you can extend $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ to a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on the affine plane itself (cf. EGA I, p. 174 here:  http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1960__4_/PMIHES_1960__4__5_0/PMIHES_1960__4__5_0.pdf)
Now since we are on the affine space, $\mathcal{F}=\tilde{M}$, where $M$ is a finitely generated module over $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$. 

Comment: We already know that $M$ is free when localized at any prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ other than $(X,Y)$ because $\tilde{M}$ was the extension of $\mathcal{F}^\prime$. Now localize both $M$ and $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ at the ideal $(X,Y)$. You get a regular two-dimensional local ring and a vector bundle $M_{(X,Y)}$ on its punctured spectrum and Corollary 4.1.1 says it's free. This shows $M$ is a vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$. By Serre's Problem $M$ must be free then.

Comment: Thanks Mahdi Majidi-Zolbanin for the great answer! I think I finally understand now. Thanks also Hailong Dao for giving the short version of this answer already from the beginning (sorry I didn't know about the extension result from EGA I, p. 174 so that I could follow what you meant). Thanks also Martin Brandenburg for your input - I'll see if I manage to come up with a simple algebraic proof sometime soon. 

Comment: Just to make sure I understand right: the corollary 4.1.1 is used in order to show that $\mathcal F$ has a free stalk above the origin - and this gives a trivialization in some neighbourhood of the origin. The conclusion is that $\mathcal F$ is a vector bundle on the affine plane - and as such it has to be free. Thanks again everybody for great answers and comments!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.